# Why can't i give space as input in following code?

Tags: c++

See the below code. If i give a "space" input for variable name, another integer variable is not being stored in the file. Why?
I've posted the outputs too.

```
    #include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int age;
    char name[100];

    ofstream obj,obj10;
    obj.open("lol.dat", ios::trunc);
    cout<<"Enter Name"<<endl;

    cin.getline(name,100);
    cin.ignore();
    obj<<name<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter age"<<endl;

    cin>>age;
    cin.ignore();
    obj10<<age<<endl;
    obj.close();
    //read

    ifstream obj2;
    obj2.open("lol.dat");
    obj2>>name;
    cout<<"Name:"<<name<<endl;
    obj2>>age;
    cout<<"Age:"<<age<<endl;
    obj2.close();
    return 0;
}
```

My outputs:

```
 Enter Name
Ankith

Enter age
1234
Name:Ankith
Age:1234

Enter Name
Ankith Prabhas

Enter age
12345
Name:Ankith
Age:0
```

What do i need to do to take the complete name "Ankith Prabhas" as one input and another integer?

Comment: By default `operator>>` stops reading when it hits whitespace, use `getline` again to read the whole name line.

Comment: Yeah sorry posted a wrong code previously. Please see this code and help me getting my desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use getline() in strings where you expect spaces.

Comment: Really sorry @Akash sinha posted a wrong code previously.
Used cin.getline() but still failed to take spaces.

Comment: program is fine, but you need to use getline during reading from file : getline(obj2,name);

Comment: So you meant that getline should be used while reading the line from the file?
In that case, as per your suggestion, obj2 is an object. So, how can i use an object for reading the line?

Comment: Yeah got it!
obj.getline(name,100);
Thanks so much bro! :)
Appreciate it! :)

Comment: obj2 is a buffer which does not read from standard buffer, instead it is taking the input from the file, similar to cin and cout, so you definitely can use obj2 in getline.

Comment: try using getline(obj2,name) during read, it will work as well :)